# TO_DATE returning different dates for different format masks?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I am having query on the below sql.
Please help me.

```
 select to_date(sysdate, 'DD MONTH YYYY') , to_date(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
 from dual where 
 to_date(sysdate, 'DD MONTH YYYY') < to_date(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

1) to_date(sysdate, 'DD MONTH YYYY') this will give Date object without time (may be time is 00:00). 
Am i correct ? If not how will i get only Date object without Time in it? 
2) From the above query It seems  to_date(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') is greater than to_date(sysdate, 'DD MONTH YYYY'). Why ??

**Update**

---

1) My aim in the above URL is to find out to_date function will only return date (or along with time) though format 'DD MONTH YYYY' is not mentioning the time chars(hh:mm..) in it. 
2) From the response i got that to_date will return Date with time always though we didn't mention the time chars. 
3) Finally to get only DATE we should use trunc() / to_date(to_char(sysdate,'mm-dd-yyyy'),'mm-dd-yyyy')

Check the below

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
to_char(to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
from dual;
```

-->hh24  :24 is important to get 00:00 format.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to convert `sysdate` which is already a date into a date.

Comment: Why not try **timestamp** is best to where

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you've just shot yourself in the foot. its called implicit datatype conversion.

there is no `TO_DATE(date)` (which is what you're asking for) , so oracle has converted your query to `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate), 'DD MONTH YYYY')` where `TO_CHAR(sysdate)` will pick up the default NLS format mask. depending on your default mask (see NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS), your 1st may have resolved to the year 0012 and the 2nd to the year 0018. so 0012 is less than 0018.

if you want to truncate the sysdate, then just do `trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: trunc(sysdate) will return only date without time ??

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar yes. the time will be 00:00:00. how it DISPLAYS is entirely up to the format mask that your client is using.

Comment: Can i use to_date(to_char(sysdate,'mm-dd-yyyy'),'mm-dd-yyyy') to truncate time ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar just do trunc(sysdate) as i said. it's the correct way to do it. your way, is the same result, just a overly complex way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the time part when selecting SYSDATE. You may set NLS_DATE_FORMAT before issuing a SELECT statement.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

In IDEs (Today, PLSQL Developer, SQL Developer etc.) **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** can be set permanently to be used by every select statement you execute. In that case you dont need to run **ALTER SESSION** command prior to SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1. In my test environment I got date with time:

```
select to_date('15 Maj 1998', 'DD MONTH YYYY') from dual;
```

Result (for Polish settings):

```
1998-05-15 00:00:00
```

Ad. 2. Why do you use `sysdate` when calling `to_date`? This function expects string describing datetime in given format. In my environment such call fails. You probably have other NLS settings so `sysdate` can be cast to string and such string gives you strange result. Use string, not `sysdate`.